# Bounding the Density of the Maximum of N Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have random variables $X_i$ with $i \in 1, ... N$. Is it true that the density of $\max{X_i}$ is bounded by the sum of the densities of $X_i$?

I read the above statement in a paper. In that context, I had that $X_i$ are independent normal random variables, but the statement did not appeal to those specifics.

I saw that $P(\max \lt r) \lt \sum P(X_i \lt r)$ but then I ran in to trouble trying to talk about densities. Taking derivatives does not preserve order in general. I will follow up on the hint given which suggests using independence.

Comment: 80+ questions, please add your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With independence I have $P(\max \lt r) = \prod P(X_i \lt r) $
With identical distribution I have $P(\max \lt r) = P(X_1 \lt r)^N $

Now taking derivative I have $f_\max(r) = N P(X_1 \lt r)^{N-1}f_1(r) \le Nf_1(r) = \sum f_i(r)$ using the fact that probabilty $P$ is bounded by $1$.

Now without identical distribution we have $f_\max(r) = \sum f_i(r)\prod_{j \ne i}P(X_j < r)$ Again using the bound $P \le 1$ we get $f_\max(r) \le \sum f_i(r)$

Thanks to Henry for the hints.

I think the statement can hold without independence.
Choose segment $S$ in the real line.
If $\max \in S$ then one of the $X_i \in S$. Then we get the relation
$$P(\max\in S) \le P(\cup_i \{X_i \in S\}) \le \sum P(X_i \in S)$$

Dividing through by the length of $S$, we have
$$ P(\max\in S)/|S| \le \sum P(X_i \in S)/|S|$$

Now taking a limit with left endpoint of $S$ fixed at $r$, and $|S| \rightarrow 0$, we get $$f_\max(r) \le \sum f_i(r)$$

Comment: Yes it seems I had given up too easily

Comment: It says it needs 20 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Given the densities $f_i(x)$ and cumulative distribution functions $F_i(x)$, and assuming independence, you can find and expression for the cumulative distribution function of the maximum  $F_\max (x)$ as a product.
- You can take the derivative of this with respect to $x$ to give  a density for the maximum of $f_\max(x)$ as a sum.
- Knowing probabilities lie in the interval $[0,1]$, you can compare this with $\sum_i f_i(x)$ and decide whether there is a bound and, if it is, then whether it is a lower or upper bound.
- You do not need to use the normal distribution.

Comment: It turns out we don't even need independence! (See my answer)