# Bounding the density of random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, order-statistics

This is a followup to the question in [Bounding the Density of the Maximum of N Random Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961506/bounding-the-density-of-the-maximum-of-n-random-variables)

I have a random variable, X, whose cdf is bounded as below:

$ \Pr \{X \le x \} \le  \underset{i}{\prod} \Pr\left\{\xi_i \le x\right\} $,

How do I bound the density  of $X$ ?

Can it be written as $f_X \le \sum_i f_{\xi_i} \prod_{j \ne i} \Pr\left\{\xi_j \le x\right\}$.

I am trying to write a proof for the above. Any  hints ?

Comment: @Mark Could you take a look ?